# How to check if a test ad is ready

Tags: unity, advertisements

I was going through UnityAds for Unity3D, and came across this setting:

> AD TEST MODE
>
> Force all

So as I understood it states that I will be able to see real ads, in test mode, without monetizations on my testing tool, which in my case is Unity3D IDE, but I am still getting that blue sample ad screen "Here would be your ad screen". Is there anything that I can do to check if any ad is placed for my app, and check this via code before `Advertisement.Show();` statement? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I am by no means an expert on this, but i played a little bit around with that. If you see the blue screen everything is fine in editor mode you will always see the blue screen stating that your advertisment would come here. If you build it then you will see the ad if you configured your app correctly.

I used it like this:

Advertisement.Initialize("YourAppIDGoesHere");
if (Advertisement.isReady() )
{
    Advertisement.Show();
}

For More Information check out the Unity documentation:

https://unityads.unity3d.com/help/Documentation%20for%20Publishers/Integration-Guide-for-Unity-Asset-Store

Comment: I am doing the same thing but no luck.